# Authentication flows when a web app authenticate visitors and itself towards Microsoft Graph

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to build a small web application that will authenticate the visiting user with Azure AD and then add the user to a specified group in Azure AD. Components used are C#/dotnet core, MSAL and Microsoft Graph library for .NET.

The steps are simple enough:

1. user visits website.
2. user gets authenticated towards Azure AD
   w/OpenID Connect.
3. when successfully authenticated, the website
   adds the user as member in a specific Azure AD group using Microsoft
   Graph API.
4. user is presented with the status of the operation.

The application is registered in Azure AD with implicit grant (for ID tokens) and with the following Azure AD permissions:

- Microsoft Graph: Group.ReadWrite.All
- Microsoft Graph: User.Read.All

The controller looks like this:

```
    public async Task<string> Test()
    {
        //get authenticated user
        var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        string preferred_username = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "preferred_username")?.Value;

        //get appsettings.json
        var azureAdOptions = new AzureADOptions();
        _configuration.Bind("AzureAd", azureAdOptions);

        //do Microsoft Graph stuff
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
            async requestMessage =>
            {
                string authority = $"{azureAdOptions.Instance}{azureAdOptions.TenantId}";

                ClientCredential clientCredentials = new ClientCredential(azureAdOptions.ClientSecret);

                var app = new ConfidentialClientApplication(azureAdOptions.ClientId, authority, "https://daemon",
                                                            clientCredentials, null, new TokenCache());

                string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

                // Passing tenant ID to the sample auth provider to use as a cache key
                AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
                authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(scopes);

                // Append the access token to the request
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
            }));

        User userToAdd = await graphClient.Users[preferred_username].Request().GetAsync();
        await graphClient.Groups["c388b7a4-2a22-4e3f-ac11-900cef9f74c6"].Members.References.Request().AddAsync(userToAdd);

        return $"added {userToAdd.DisplayName} to group";
    }
```

Startup.cs looks like this:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
        });

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

With this code I have two authentication flows. One for authenticating the visiting user and one for authenticating the app towards Microsoft Graph. The rationale behind this is that the user does not hold enough permissions to add a member to the group. The code works and does exactly as expected.

Is the double authentication flow against a single Azure AD app registration the best way to ensure this goal or is there a sleeker design where only one authentication flow is needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know you do need to support these two flows.  Your user needs one token to talk to your web application and your web application needs a different token to talk to Graph.

Hopefully you won't need all that code in the DelegateAuthenticationProvider soon as we will be previewing a bunch of scenario based AuthenticationProviders shortly.  The [ClientCredentialProvider](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth/blob/MsalAuthProvider/src/Microsoft.Graph.Auth/ConfidentialClient/ClientCredentialProvider.cs) should do all that work for you.

Comment: Is it considered bad practice (or insecure) to support both flows with a single app registration in Azure AD, i.e. should the two flows be registered as two individual apps in Azure AD?

Comment: @agnsaft I believe it is fine.  You application is acting as both a resource owner and resource consumer.  That is perfectly natural.

Comment: Could the same be achieved by using On-Behalf-of flow rather than client credential flow, and if so, would the user object have to be granted additional permissions or would it be sufficient to add additional delegated permissions to the app?

Comment: Yes you can use the on-behalf-of-flow.  Your question about whether the user must consent is a great question.  I will investigate.

Comment: Actually, it was not so much about consent, but rather if the entire user object must have sufficient privileges (e.g. be owner of the group from the example above) or if delegated permissions with admin consent on the application will ensure that the user don't need the privileges themselves.